# How to generate custom url in php? (Not url shortner)

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

I am creating a website where people can see each others profiles and I want to open their profile with specific links like `https://www.example.com/johnsmith`.

`johnsmith` is the custom URL. How can I generate the custom URLs in PHP like `https://www.example.com/abc`? In this case ‍‍‍`/abc` is the custom one. How can I create this custom URL via `PHP` or `JavaScript`? And yes I am **not** talking about a **URL shortener**!

Comment: Also, you can ask your hosting partner about this config as well if its a bit hard. I also think DirectAdmin and such tools provide these settings as well. I don't use them so my anser is based on logical thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It is something which is handled by your WebServer. e.g. you have this url:

```
http://example.com/?action=abc
```

then you will rewrite it like this

```
http://example.com/abc
```

In apache you can achieve so with using this code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_.0-9]+) ?action=$1
```

The code says your url should start with any number or string but we don't know about the ending. you can specify the ending by adding a `$` at the end of your Regex.

I wonder if you know how to work with htaccess or not. Anyway it is something totally different and can not be explained in just a sentence. Just a tutorial on htaccess

[htaccess](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess)

Answer (score -2):

You need to 'rewrite' URL's on the server-side. Like in Apache or nGinx. You can't just do it with PHP or JavaScript.

For example in nGinx:

```
rewrite ^(/willsmith/.*)$ /mypath/pages/willsmith.html last;
```

Comment: How can i do this bro?

Comment: Consider proving a short example !

Comment: Edit your server config. Enable rewrite. For apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html   For nGinx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html